# NeuronJ plugin in ImageJ .JAR file not opening on MAC OSX10.10.4

Tags: java, plugins, jar, imagej

I am trying to download and add a specific plugin called NeuronJ to ImageJ. ImageJ downloads fine and I can open it. The .JAR file for the NeuronJ plugin downloads but does not open and the MAC gives me the following message 'The Java JAR file NeuronJ.jar could not be launched, check the console for possible error messages'. Would anyone know how to solve this problem? The website I am using to download this from is:http://www.imagescience.org/meijering/software/neuronj/

Answer (score 1):

NeuronJ.jar is an ImageJ plugin - so you don't execute it directly. You put it in a place ImageJ will find it on startup (the `{ImageJ}/plugins` directory). Directions for manual installation can be found [on the wiki](http://imagej.net/Plugins#Installing_plugins_manually).

Once you install the plugin manually you just restart ImageJ and then NeuronJ should be available from the `Plugins` menu.